# setting up filesystem permissions

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Directoryd = "D:";
            string mydirectory = Directoryd + "\\" + "rs\\";
            if (!Directory.Exists(mydirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(mydirectory); 
            }
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(mydirectory);
            DirectorySecurity ds = di.GetAccessControl();


            ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"*",FileSystemRights.FullControl,AccessControlType.Allow));
           di.SetAccessControl(ds);





        }
    }
}
```

this is my code when i execute this the pop up is showing that 
Actually, this code is to create a folder rs and set its permission to deny full control but on running the error come with the message
    Some or all identity references could not be translated.
What is the error?

Comment: Whats the * for? If thats for Everyone than you should probably try the everyone group

Comment: It's "Everyone" as in "gokul-PC\gokul"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the following line:

```
 ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"*",FileSystemRights.FullControl,AccessControlType.Allow));
```

to:

```
 ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"Everyone",FileSystemRights.FullControl,AccessControlType.Allow));
```

Also if you look at the following [Everyone Group](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/dc841874-b71b-4e1c-9052-06eb4a87d08f/) there is an answer a bit further down that suggests you should use SSID's instead of the names.

Comment: answer was great but adding directory on directorySecurity commited mistakes/errors on compiler

Answer (score 1):

Try the group "Everyone", not *.