# Need help simulating an exception in C#?

Tags: c#, command-line, exception

I am trying to simulate an error but I am have trouble accomplishing this. My source code below should look at every drive in and find a folder or file with the that you passed in as arguments. Then it writes what it has found to the drive (%SystemDrive%) in a log file(.log). The code works on my local machine but when someone else tries to run it, they get an UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\ARAGORN.log' is denied. For some weird reason, the person cannot write the results to a that log file and I don't understand why. Can someone see if the can simulate this Exception. Please run this from the command line or powershell.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Management;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Collections;

/***
 *                                                                                          
 *  Written by:                                                                                          
 *                                                                                          
 *  Description: Look through every single drive to find files with the name <the file that you are look of> (Specify name in the string theString).
 *               All files are then stored in an ArrayList called fileList.
 *  
 *  Notes: If a file does note have the exact name, it will be ignored.
 *         This only finds files with the name you are looking for. Directories will be ignored.
 *                                                                                          
 * 
 * */
namespace FileFinder
{
    class Program
    {
        static ArrayList fileList = new ArrayList();
        static ArrayList folderList = new ArrayList();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("There are this many args: " + args.Length);
            if(args.Length < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too few arguments");
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            else if(args.Length > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too many arguments");
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            //change the name you search for a specific file name
            //Console.WriteLine("Enter the file name");
            string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            string theString = args[0];
            foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                string drive = d.Name;
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Looking in " + drive + " for " + theString);
                    LookForFileInDir(drive, theString);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }


            }
            //Console.WriteLine("The Host Name is: " + hostName);
            Console.WriteLine("There are " + fileList.Count + " files that were found with the name " + theString);
            Console.WriteLine("There are " + folderList.Count + " folders that were found with the name " + theString);



            var actualPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemDrive%\"+hostName+".log");
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(actualPath ))
            {
                file.WriteLine("bytes\t" + "file");
                foreach (string f in fileList)
                {
                    file.WriteLine(f);
                }
                file.WriteLine();
                file.WriteLine("\t" + "folder");
                foreach (string folder in folderList)
                {
                    file.WriteLine(folder);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /**
         * 
         * Looks for files in directories
         * 
         * */
        static void LookForFileInDir(string folder, string theString)
        {
            string output = "";
            //Console.WriteLine("I am not losing my mind");
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*" + theString + "*.*"))
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("I am not losing my mind");
                if (!IsLink(file))
                {
                    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
                    Console.WriteLine(info.Length + "\t" + file);
                    fileList.Add(info.Length + "\t" + file);
                    output += file;
                }
            }

            foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder, theString))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + subDir);
                    folderList.Add("\t" + subDir);
                }
                //Ignores all shortcuts in a drive
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
                {

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    output += e.Message;
                }
            }


            foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
            {
                try
                {
                    LookForFileInDir(subDir, theString);

                }
                //Ignores all shortcuts in a drive
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
                {

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    output += e.Message;
                }
            }

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns whether the given path/file is a link
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="shortcutFilename"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsLink(string shortcutFilename)
        {
            string pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(shortcutFilename);
            string filenameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(shortcutFilename);

            Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
            Shell32.Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(pathOnly);
            Shell32.FolderItem folderItem = folder.ParseName(filenameOnly);
            if (folderItem != null)
            {
                return folderItem.IsLink;
            }
            return false; // not found
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried executing the program with admin rights? Alternatively put the log file in the Temp folder instead of root C:

Comment: what are the read/write permissions on the file? Can you give Full Control to everyone?

Comment: I have a good feeling about what @Piters said. A lot of the time this can happen when you have read access but not write access to a location. I ran into this particular problem when creating a subdirectory for a log file in a place I couldn't write.

Comment: In newer versions of Windows post XP the root folder does not have write permission for standard users to my experience. Running the app as administrator will of course give you access.

Comment: I would assume that the user ran the program as a admin in powershell, but even without admin rights, I was still able to run write to the file. Most files that are created in out network should be view-able to all authenticated users. Plus, it is his own machine.

Answer (score 0):

Command Prompt, by default, doesn't run with admin rights.  On Windows Vista or higher the C-drive is locked down from being written to without admin rights (or without disabling UAC and some security).

I would suggest changing the location of your log file.  Desktop would be a good place, and you can use the special folders to place it for any user.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

Other folder choices are [available from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) and you might need to give some pushback if your manager wants the system folder but the end users can't use elevated permissions. If they can, make sure they run as administrator.

We can also tell that the exception is folder access permissions because:

1. It isn't from expanding the environmental variable. If *this* fails, it throws `ArgumentNullException`.
2. The exception points to UAC. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx) covers the reason for this exception:

> An UnauthorizedAccessException exception is typically thrown by a method that 
>   wraps a Windows API call. To find the reasons for the exception,
>   examine the text of the exception object's Message property.
>   UnauthorizedAccessException uses the HRESULT COR_E_UNAUTHORIZEDACCESS,
>   which has the value 0x80070005.

Comment: I don't think it is an admin rights problem. I ran it without admin rights and I was still able to write to the log file. Could the problem be with the fact that the person ran it in powershell. I was told to write it to the %SystemDrive% so I cannot change the location.

Comment: The error is fairly clear -- it doesn't have access to that file.  Windows doesn't like creating files on the root drive.  Unauthorized access means it does not have permissions to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate the exception just deny your debug user write access to C:\

Comment: I am new to Visual Studio, how would I go about doing that.

Comment: Either do it in the OS. Or programmatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472974/setting-up-filesystem-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Actually root C: is not a good place to dump files - the standard Windows access restriction makes sense in this way. In your place I would consider moving the log file i. e. to the Temp folder (as stated in my first comment). This should solve the problem.

However if you insist keeping the file as is, I would make sure to execute the program with admin rights. This should also solve the problem.